# Bootstrap: Accordion not auto collapsing previously opened panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a bootstrap accordion. The markup below works fine, but it does not auto-collapse the previously opened element. For example, open panel1, then click on panel2.. panel1 should then auto-close, but it does not. I have tried copying the markup exactly from the bootstrap site (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse), but it is not working. What am I missing?

```
<h3>ACCORDION DEMO</h3>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="accordion1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel1">Panel 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="panel1">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>This is accordion panel 1 content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="accordion1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel2">Panel 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="panel2">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p>This is accordion panel 2 content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

simply replace `data-parent="accordion1"` with `data-parent="#accordion1"`

Answer (score 10):

For posterity, another reason I just discovered that would prevent the accordion panels from auto-collapsing is if the `.panel` elements are not direct children of the accordion (`.panel-group` element).  I had wrapped my panel content in a `div` within my `.panel-group` and the accordion didn't like that.

Comment: This is the problem I was experiencing.  I'm integrating this into a Drupal view and I had to edit the view templates to remove the divs between panels.

Comment: How did you work around this? What do you use instead of <div>?

Comment: @ErikThiart I removed the `<div>`.  `.panel` must be a direct child of `.panel-group`.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same behavior, I removed the bootstrap transition module and it worked. Also fixed the issue with disappearing popovers.

Answer (score -3):

I was facing the same problem and did some changes based on a hunch.. It worked and now I would like to share my findings in case it may help someone.. I was using accordion collapse feature on more than one pages which was making them act strangely.. giving different panels unique href and panel id helped.