# Closing accordion panels when another opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on an accordion panel group. They all open just fine, but I can't figure out how to get them to close upon opening another element.

Here is what I'm working on in terms of code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="trickslist">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="expand">
            <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
            <div>
              <h2 class="tipstricks">Exploring your Motivations to Quit Tobacco</h2>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="detail">

          </div>
        </li>           
        <li>
          <a class="expand">
            <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
            <h2 class="tipstricks">Avoiding weight gain or alcohol</h2>
          </a>
          <div class="detail">

          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="expand">
            <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
            <h2 class="tipstricks">Making your plan stick: relapse prevention</h2>
          </a>
          <div class="detail">

          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to create new ids to call in JS/JQuery code, but nothing seems to be working.

```
var $myGroup = $('#trickslist');
$myGroup.on('show.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function () {
    $myGroup.find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

I figure it's in my script, but I'm not 100% on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: May be this post will help your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645501/bootstrap-accordion-not-auto-collapsing-previously-opened-panel

Comment: didn't seem to solve the issue, unfortunately. Other panels remain open. I put together a fiddle to show what I have: https://fiddle.jshell.net/28zhrrcd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle, hope that solves your problem =)
Here is the jQuery. Check out the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kymera28/99rgmm66/5/)

```
$(".expand").on("click", function () {
    $(".right-arrow").text("+");
    $(".detail:visible").slideUp();
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")){

        $(this).next().slideDown(200);
        $(this).find(".right-arrow").text("-");
    }
});
```

[EDITED]


On an ".expand" element click event all accordions will return to their initial state, closed and with the plus sign on the right. The accordion's detail section will only appear if that accordion is closed, to prevent it from hiding and appearing if clicked when opened. If the accordion is closed the detail section will appear and the plus sign will change to the minus one.

Comment: Please explain what you did so the rest of us can understand :-)

Comment: That worked great. I didn't even think about using :visible. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

From your fiddle I can't see anything's expanding right now but there is a simple trick to achieve that functionality: at click hide all and than show just that particular.

```
$(".expand").click(function(){
    $(".detail").collaps();
    $(this).parent().find(".detail").expand();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a lot of time, grief, and maintenance by using a library that already has this functionality.  Both jQuery UI and Kendo UI are tried-and-tested and have been used by developers all over the world.  Someone else has already worked out the kinks.  Work smart!  (I don't work for either.)

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/panelbar/api